# is there way in windows to have just one application start in high contrast mode?

Tags: windows

There seems to be a lot of information on the web on how to set high contrast mode for the entire windows desktop, but I am wondering if there was a way to set high contrast mode for just a single application when it starts up.  For instance, let's say I want something from microsoft office (Outlook, Word, Excel) to start up in high contrast mode but nothing else to start up in high contrast mode?

Comment: I'm still looking for this.